# How to simulate oAuth 2.0 flow in Postman with Authorization Code

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, bearer-token

I am creating an automated testing collection in Postman, and I want to retrieve the Bearer Token using the oAuth 2.0 flow with authorization code.

**I am struggling with how to configure a "listener" mock of redirect uri that will be able to receive the authorization code (in Postman).**

I was able to create the next step of initiate a new call to get the token (using the authorization code).

---

My flow step by step, the problematic step is 5:

1. App send API request for permissions
2. App receive back a redirect link for user authorization
3. User authorizes the permission request
4. App initiate authorization flow (../oauth/authorize)
5. **App receive to it's predefined 'redirect uri' the authorization code**
6. App send request to GET token with the authorization code received

---

I am using Postman, and tried their callback uri, without any success.